# Encounterin "NoneType Error" when using Dask to Read Nested JSON file

Tags: python, bigdata, dask, nonetype, dask-dataframe

I'm trying to use dask bag to first read the nested big json file and then flatten it to a dask dataframe, and then save it as a csv. However, I encountered a nonetype error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" during the flattening. Here are my code:

```
    b = db.read_text('2019-12-16-latest-level.json').map(json.loads)

    def flatten(record):
        return {
            'uuid': record['uuid'],
            'level_id': record['level_instance_json']['meta']['level_id'],
            'previous_attempts': record['level_instance_json']['meta']['previous_attempts'],
            'early_termination': record['level_instance_json']['meta']['early_termination'],
            'platform': record['level_instance_json']['meta']['platform'],
            'app_version': record['level_instance_json']['meta']['app_version']
    }
```

Data looks like this,

```
    {'uuid': 'bef72f2d-f0af-447b-a173-9f04979cc35f',
      'level_instance_json': {'meta': {'user_id': 0,
        'level_id': 13,
        'previous_attempts': 1,
        'early_termination': False,
        'platform': 'ANDROID',
        'app_version': '1.2.2',}}}
```

Here is the error:

```
    <ipython-input-71-3c5cd8597f07> in flatten(record)
    ----> 6         'level_id': record['level_instance_json']['meta']['level_id'],
          7         'previous_attempts': record['level_instance_json']['meta']['previous_attempts'],
          8         'early_termination': record['level_instance_json']['meta']['early_termination'],

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I'd like to omit the user whose data has a "none" in level_id when I'm loading the data to avoid the error. Any suggestions?

Comment: In your data, I noticed an extra ````(``` with no closing ```)```.

Comment: Thanks. Just removed the extra "("

Comment: what happens if you do a ```print(record)``` before the return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the raw json does not contain the necessary field, this will trigger a computation error by dask. One option for avoiding that is to use `.get` instead of directly referencing the key, for example:

```py
# 'level_id': record['level_instance_json']['meta']['level_id']
'level_id': record.get('level_instance_json', {'meta': {'level_id': 'n/a/'})['meta']['level_id']
```

The second argument to `.get` is what python will use if the key is not available, so you want to put here something that will not trigger further errors (e.g. by providing the expected keys with a missing/not available value).

Answer (score 0):

I had to reform your json to the format shown below, because I think dask follows json rules strictly ,[Please study few json syntax standard. I don't have an in depth idea about that]

```
{"uuid": "bef72f2d-f0af-447b-a173-9f04979cc35f","level_instance_json": {"meta": {"user_id":0,"level_id":13,"previous_attempts": 1,"early_termination": false,"platform": "ANDROID","app_version": "1.2.2"}}}
```

Then I called your flatten function in this format :

```
 flatten(b.take(1)[0])
```

It worked fine.

[image]

Basically ,I have removed all the new line from your json file and used double quote instead of single quote.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my question. I did not write that json data format. I just copy-pasted the output. The sample data in the example should be read fine (I was showing as an example of the data structure), it's another data that produced the "nonetype" error.